# How to find position (array index ) of a number in a given array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have to find the position (array index) of a number in an array, the number can lie in between any other two numbers in the array. I have written code for this but I want some alternative way to do this.

example: let the array be given as

```
float arr[]={1.5, 3.65, 4.9, 8.4, 10.6, 17.5, 19.45, 21.86, 25.67, 30.65};
```

Now I have to find the position of 12.6 in the given array, since 12.6 lies between 10.6 and 17.5 in the above array so, it should return array index as 4. **Is there any other way to do this?**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int position;
    int i;
    float num=12.6; // position of this number has to be determined i.e. it lies between 10.6 
                    // and 17.5 in the array given below so it should give array index as 4 
    float arr[]={1.5, 3.65, 4.9, 8.4, 10.6, 17.5, 19.45, 21.86, 25.67, 30.65}; // any random array

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] < num)
        {
            position=i;
        }
    }
    printf("array index is %d",position); // this gives index as 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do a binary search, under the assumption that the array is sorted.

Comment: @Tarik was faster than me.The array in your example is sorted. Was it just luck or it is a requirement for the input array?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes, the array is sorted (in ascending order). I know that I can perform a binary search but I don't know how to implement it in this case (where the number is not the part of the array)

Comment: In your code, add a "break;" after "position=i;", so you exit the loop as soon as the number is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this interesting method:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    float arr[] = {1.5, 3.65, 4.9, 8.4, 10.6, 17.5, 19.45, 21.86, 25.67, 30.65};
    short int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    float input;

    std::cout << "Number to find: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] <= input && arr[i + 1] >= input) {
            std::cout << "Array element exists: " << i << " | "
                      << "Range: " << arr[i] << " & " << arr[i + 1] << std::endl;

            break;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

This program straightforwardly gets the size of arrays dynamically and loops until it finds the range where the number exists. If so, then print the value and breaks the loop.

### Sample Output

```
Number to find: 12.6
Array element exists: 4 | Range: 10.6 & 17.5
```

Extra example:

```
Number to find: 30.65 // called the last index value
Array element exists: 8 | Range: 25.67 & 30.65 // still works
```

---

**Disclaimer:** The `arr[i + 1]` may try to access out of bound element and not always required to output correct behavior, it may throw undefined behavior too. But in this case, the answer shows expected output.

Comment: `arr[i + 1]` is outside the array on the last iteration.

Comment: If a number given is outside of range, then it won't print anything simply. And if you give the value of last index, it'll still work. I was having this conception too, but when I tried, it worked.

Comment: Accessing memory past the end of an array is undefined behavior, a terrible bug, and "it works on my machine" doesn't make it correct.

Comment: That I know, but I don't know if there's any method to get range of two values forbidding accessing the end of an array in the last iteration. In this case, there was no  other simpler method to achieve the OP's requirement.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I've added another working example output in the answer for your satisfaction nevertheless it tries to access out of bound array element.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a disclaimer to your answer that it leads to undefined behavior and therefore isn't required to return reasonable results.

Comment: @Blastfurnace disclaimer appended to the answer.